# « Un fichier de données » — Pourquoi « données » ?

Tags: étymologie, informatique, mathématiques

Est-ce que le mot « données », qui est utilisé en informatique, vient du terme mathématique que l'on utilise dans les équations : les **données** et les inconnues ?

Comment: And it's a literal translation in English. `Les données d'un problème` are what is **given** to solve the problem and its unknowns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oui. Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donn%C3%A9e) donne

1. Le sens premier de *donnée* est mathématique: quantité fournie dans l'énoncé qui permet de donner la solution à un problème.
2. Par extension, ce qui est connu et admis, et qui sert de base, à un raisonnement, à un examen ou à une recherche.
3. Par spécialisation, information élémentaire qui permet un traitement automatisé des informations